# Retrieve error response from parseJSON logic apps

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

Can you retrieve the error message from Parse JSON step on failure?
I have tried different ways of access the message, but all return the empty string
body('Parse_json')?['errors'][0]['message']

[Logic app Flow with Pars JSON with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j7iB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this expression:

```
outputs('Parse_json')['errors'][0]['message']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers my question.