# Extract exact error message from Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Logic Apps, trying to catch an error message. Had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459998/retrieve-error-response-from-parsejson-logic-apps) but didn't work.
Actually, I am trying to insert a record in Dynamics and catch the error if it fails. I am passing the following datestring "2022-01-31", that gets accepted. If someone passes it as "2022-01-311" or "0001-01-31", it should throw an error. However, in the first case, I am getting the following message in postman, Error code (502):

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "NoResponse",
    "message": "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id '08585523150489909352894492968CU26'."
}}
```

While the actual logic app error is:

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Response_-_Error_if_Add_a_new_row_fails' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['errors'][0]['message']' cannot be evaluated because property 'errors' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

In the second case, the error is:

```
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Response_-_Error_if_Add_a_new_row_fails' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['errors'][0]['message']' cannot be evaluated because property 'errors' doesn't exist, available properties are 'statusCode, headers, body'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

Code I am using to display the error message is:

```
outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['errors'][0]['message']'
```

Also, tried this before:

```
@actions('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['error']
```

but was getting this for both cases:

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Response_-_Error_if_Add_a_new_row_fails' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'actions('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['message']' cannot be evaluated because property 'message' doesn't exist, available properties are 'name, startTime, endTime, trackingId, clientTrackingId, code, status, error'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Response_-*Error_if_Add_a_new_row_fails' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'actions('D365*-_Add_a_new_row')['error']' cannot be evaluated because property 'error' doesn't exist, available properties are 'name, inputs, outputs, startTime, endTime, trackingId, clientTrackingId, code, status'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Looks like the errors object doesn't exist in one case but I need a proper way to display this.

How can I extract the actual message from CRM which is something like:
"Date can't be less than minimum date..." and "Invalid date format".

[image]

This is the JSON.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Date is less than the minumum value supported by CrmDateTime. Actual value: 01/31/0001 00:00:00, Minimum value supported: 01/01/1753 00:00:00",
  "error": {
    "message": "Date is less than the minumum value supported by CrmDateTime. Actual value: 01/31/0001 00:00:00, Minimum value supported: 01/01/1753 00:00:00"
  },
  "source": "eap-dev.crm6.dynamics.com",
  "errors": [],
  "debugInfo": "clientRequestId: aef24252-7969-44b0-8d10-2caf52b166cb"
}
```

Comment: You have multiple questions.  I can answer the issue around the LogicApps errors but getting the actual error from Dynamics is a different story.  Want the first answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change this ...

```
outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['errors'][0]['message']
```

... to this ...

```
outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['error']['message']
```

... or even easier based on the example, you can just go for the top level message.

```
outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['message']
```

`errors` as a property has no other values in it, so avoid that one I'd say.

The `[0]` is never going to work because that notation is looking for the first element in an array and your JSON response is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: It's giving me this message now in both cases (502 Bad gateway):
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Response_-_Error_if_Add_a_new_row_fails' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'outputs('D365_-_Add_a_new_row')['errors']['message']' cannot be evaluated because property 'errors' doesn't exist, available properties are 'statusCode, headers, body'. Please ...

Body('D365_-_Add_a_new_row'), then it catches error from Dynamics and shows 400 with error message, but doesn't show error message in second case.

Comment: You need to show a screenshot (or provide the json) for the result from the add a new row action.

Comment: Please check the screenshot in my edited post

Comment: I need the output, it's impossible to help without the actual output.  Is that available?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you, what output are you talking about?

Comment: The output from D365 add a new row.  You've given the postman response up there but what's the exact output that's coming from that action after it executes and fails?

Comment: If it helps, write `outputs('D365-Add_a_new_row')` to a string variable and show us what that looks like.

Comment: For the first scenario:

{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Date is less than the minumum value supported by CrmDateTime. Actual value: 01/31/0001 00:00:00, Minimum value supported: 01/01/1753 00:00:00",
  "error": {
    "message": "Date is less than the minumum value supported by CrmDateTime. Actual value: 01/31/0001 00:00:00, Minimum value supported: 01/01/1753 00:00:00"
  },
  "source": "eap-dev.crm6.dynamics.com",
  "errors": [],
  "debugInfo": "clientRequestId: aef24252-7969-44b0-8d10-2caf52b166cb"
}

Comment: for the second scenario:

Unable to process template language expressions in action 'D365_-_Add_a_new_row' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string '2022-01-311' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the action and the output, therefore, I have now provided an answer which works off an object variable.  If that doesn't work then we may need to transform the result into an object before trying to pull back properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in how you access error message of an action and of an action which is inside Scope.

Go through following article, should help getting more insights.
https://www.tech-findings.com/2022/06/Exception-Handling-in-Logic-app.html